Help with Engineering Statics

I have no idea how to start solving this question. The homework is past due and I want to figure out the solution for this question.

Don't bother, I don't think this system will work as intended, too much information was missing.

Draw a Free Body Diagram for each individual component, which means getting it into static equilibrium. So for ABC, you know there is a force at 60 degrees at B which can be resolved into two perpendicular components , one helps to resist FA+ FC's perpendicular force, and the axial force is reacted at C as well. And so on and so forth.

Similar to what @GregLocock suggested, to solve the problem, , I'd start with point E and work back, resolving the perpendicular components.  If you push straight down from point C, it accomplishes nothing. If you push to the right from point C with N pounds, you get 2/3 N pounds pushing down at point E.  When's this due?  I'll come back with an answer July 1.

The advantage here is that there are only forces in pins, no moments. Each member has to be in static equilibrium, which consists of 3 equations: sum of forces in vertical direction, sum of forces in horizontal direction and sum of moments to selected point (each of the sums must be 0). In pin connections, sum of forces in each direction also has to be zero. This in general leads to system of linear equations.

@TomášLétal that is not actually true by my interpretation of the diagram.  Member AC is continuous through joint B. Member BG is pinned at both end so only an axial force will be present in BG.  Likewise, the member CDE is a continuous member through the pin joint at D.  There will be no moment at joint C, and there will be no moment transferred  at joint D to the member DF.

@ForwardEd Yes, pins do not transfer moments, but you still need to satisfy moment equilibrium for each individual member. If you take the member ABC, there is transverse force at the end A and axial force from BG, which translates to ABC partly as axial and partly as transverse. These have to be counterbalanced by the force at pin C. There are moments in members, for example there is clearly an internal moment 20 lb * 6 inch in ABC at B.

I get a force down at point E of 24.9 pounds.
When I give job interviews, I always ask one problem for them to solve in front of me and another for them to do overnight.  This would have been an overnight problem.
My reasoning is, we have a 20# (pound) force normal to ABC at point A.  If we assume it is pivoting around point C (this is a statics problem so that is permitted), we have to counter the (10")(20#) CCW (counter clockwise) torque with a (4")(x#) CW torque.  Solving for X gives a 50# force normal to ABC at point B to keep it from rotating.  Except there is a connection at point B at 60 degrees so the force acting along G-B at point B is 50/sin(60) or 57.7#.  This means there will be a component of 57.7 cos(60) =28.9# acting along ABC towards C.
That gets us to point C.  Assuming we pivot around point B, we have a (6")(20#) or 120 inch pound torque rotating CCW so we need a (4")(x#) torque to counter or 30# acting normal to ABC upwards at point C.  This and the 28.9# parallel to ABC need to be resolved into Y and X coordinates.
$C_{y}= 30 sin(70) - 28.9 cos(70) = 18.3$#
$C_{x}= 30 cos(70) + 28.9 sin(70) = 37.4$#
It happens that point D is connected to F with a rigid connection so we can disregard the Y component for the current discussion.
Point C has a 37.4# force acting in the X direction.  If we pivot at D, that gives us (2")(37.4#) torque in CW so we need (3")(x#) pushing up at point E to counter so X is
$X = \frac{2}{3}(37.4)$# or 24.9 pounds acting down at point E.
I have not done this sort of problem in a few years so I will be interested to see if anybody sees errors in my work (or if I am completely wrong).
Later, @ForwardEd pointed out that I can't do arithmetic.  This should be correct now.
The last time I worked on something like this, I made a model in my basement and measured the forces to show I was right.  This is not that complicated, we'll see about this time.

I'm convinced this was a take home exam so I put off solving this.  I said I'd put in an answer on July 1.  July 11, that's close, No?

I set the model up in S-Frame and made the point E a roller support.  Unfortunately I had to break the applied load into -6.8404 (leftward) and -18.7939 (downward).  The reaction at E was 24.9249 (upwards).  I am not saying you are wrong.  I am just pointing out there is a disparity in the numbers

According to my model in S-Frame the horizontal load at C (max shear in CD) is 37.3787

30*COS(70d) = 10.26, 28.9*SIN(70d)=27.15.  Ergo, they sum to 37.41.  Not sure if your calculations were set to rads, gradians or what not, but maybe that is where the math went wrong. Carrying on your process with the new number, 2/3 * 37.41 = 24.95

@ForwardEd Thanks for checking my answer.  I worked it out again and I have no clue where I got those numbers from.  I wonder if I converted from degrees to radians incorrectly or something.  The answer has now been updated with your numbers.  It should be right now.   Oh no, The OP will only get half credit.  It's a good thing I gave him my answer long after it was due.
